# Formatting Strings in Java with more than two digits

Tags: java

ive been thinking on how to do this but i cant seem to get it.
How can i achieve this output

```
1         2
5         3
10        7
15        18
20        22
```

I have this:

```
1         2
5         3
10         7
15         18
20         22
```

I am using a for loop

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: If you don't show your code, it's basically impossible for anyone to help you without just handing you an answer, which doesn't help you at all in the long run. Post your code, and go do a search for "java string format". The first result contains everything you need to know in order to solve this problem.

Comment: use System.out.printf("%d \t %d",a,b);

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format specifier with a width and left-justify flag to print two items per line:

```
System.out.printf("%1$-10d%2$d%n", val1, val2);
```

or you can do each value separately:

```
System.out.printf("%1$-10d", val1);
System.out.println(val2); // or System.out.printf("%1$d%n", val2);
```

See the Java tutorial [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

See in the [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) the subject [*Formatting Numeric Print Output*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

> The `java.io` package includes a `PrintStream` class that has two formatting methods that you can use to replace `print` and `println`. These methods, `format` and `printf`, are equivalent to one another. The familiar `System.out` that you have been using happens to be a `PrintStream` object, so you can invoke `PrintStream` methods on `System.out`. Thus, you can use `format` or `printf` anywhere in your code where you have previously been using `print` or `println`.

There are several methods for to do that:

```
public PrintStream format(String format, Object... args)
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object... args)
public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```